# Pin and Unpin elements using only CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been using `position: fixed;` to pin elements on screen, but as soon as I unpin them, they disappear from the screen(after being scrolled to few lines) and appear at the beginning of the document.

***For example:***

If the element is unpinned at 5th line, it should stay at 5th line of the document, but it jumps back to the top regardless of position from where it was unpinned.

I've been pinning and unpinning as,

```
.pinned {
  position: fixed;
}

.unpinned {
  position: relative;
}
```

Link to [CodePen](http://codepen.io/snazzysanoj/pen/XXgYZY).

So, Is there any way I could set the position of the element(upon unpinning) to the ***position from which it has been unpinned*** using CSS alone(or minimal JS if not possible using pure CSS)?

P.S. I tried using `absolute`, `relative`, and also `static` while unpinning, but none seems to work.

Comment: You should also post the relevant code parts here for future reference (CodePen might be down someday).

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll edit it :)

Comment: No, I tried using `relative`, `absolute`, and also `static`, but none worked

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't do this with CSS alone. You'll need to use JavaScript to achieve the desired effect.

By changing the JavaScript to the following:

```
var el = document.getElementById('element');
function toggle(){
    if(el.className == 'pinned'){
        el.style.top = (document.body.scrollTop+el.getBoundingClientRect().top)+'px';
        el.className = 'unpinned';
    }else{
        el.style.top = el.getBoundingClientRect().top+'px';
        el.className = 'pinned';
    }
}
```

And the CSS to this:

```
.unpinned{
    position: absolute;
}
```

This code will alter the `top` attribute of the element, and then toggle between position fixed and absolute.

Comment: You're allowed to provide a JS solution to this since the question is also flagged JS/JQ (I think this is why you got the downvote) but you are correct, it isn't doable with CSS as this is something of a dynamic nature.

Comment: How is this an answer? It's a comment. An answer would be something like: "you can't do it with CSS alone... but here is how you could do it with JS.... "

Comment: @wf4 Thanks, I was just meant to ask that.. :)

Comment: The question has been edited since I had given my answer. He solely asked if this is possible with CSS only. I'll make a Fiddle. Jeez

Answer (score 1):

You can glue the element to the position it was like that:

```
var el = document.getElementById('element')
var rectObject = el.getBoundingClientRect();
var scroll = document.body.scrollTop 
el.className = 'unpinned';
el.style.top = (scroll + rectObject.top) + "px"
```

+ some code when unpinning
and

```
.unpinned {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoEGPZ
Avoid it sticking above scroll: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bERKzW

It is not possible to do it in CSS only

Comment: try to click more than 2 times

Comment: It still jumps to the top upon unpinning :(

Comment: @SnazzySanoj Fixed it

Comment: @SnazzySanoj but I would try to avoid the Element to be pinned, when it above the page scroll, because then you can not see it. If you want I can catcht that case and pull it down so the user can see it: HERE http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bERKzW

Comment: Or is there any alternative way(besides`getBoundingClientRect`) to get the  position of the element, when it's unpinned and assign that position as absolute value?

Comment: @SnazzySanoj Why? But yes and it's more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JavaScript method for retrieving position of the element relative to the view port. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect